# Why does the following identity hold in Minkowski Theory.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am once again reading Neukirch's Algebraic number theory ([http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eila/Neukirch_Algebraic_number_theory.pdf)) on page 29.

The situation is the following. One has an algebraic number field $K$ and the corresponding $n$ $\mathbb{C}$ embeddings of the field $K$, denoted by $\tau$. Obviously, one can consider the complex conjugate of this embedding (Correct me if I'm wrong: The embeddings are given by "permuting" the roots of the minimal polynomial of the primitive element of the field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, the complex conjugate of such an embedding is just given by assigning the primitive element to the complex conjugate of the root.)

Now for my question: Neukirch states that obviously $\overline{\tau}(a) = \overline{\tau}(\overline{a})$.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misreading the formula on page 29, which is $\overline{\tau}a = \overline{\tau a}$ (one big line). This is indeed the definition of $\overline{\tau}$.

Comment: Just realized this with this post (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4686852/805482). Thanks!